# using self in swift 2

Tags: ios8, swift2

i try to write this code in swift 2 :

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

struct Point {

var x: Double
var y: Double
}

func distanceTo (#point: Point) -> Double {

let a = abs(self.x - point.x)
let b = abs(self.y - point.y)

let c = sqrt(a * a + b * b)

return c
}


let pointA = Point(x: 1.0, y: 2.0)
let pointB = Point(x: 4.0, y: 6.0)
let distance = pointA.distanceTo (point: pointB)
```

but i got this error :

```
#has been remove from swift, so  i change the code to 

func distanceTo (#point: Point) -> Double
```

but then i got another error :

```
use of unresolved identifier 'self'
```

any clue how to fix this error in swift 2?

thanx

Comment: FYI, rather than `sqrt(a * a + b * b)` you could also use `hypot(a, b)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make distanceTo as the member of your Point structure- see:

```
import Foundation

struct Point {

  var x: Double
  var y: Double

  func distanceTo (point point: Point) -> Double {

    let a = abs(self.x - point.x)
    let b = abs(self.y - point.y)

    let c = sqrt(a * a + b * b)

    return c
  }
}




let pointA = Point(x: 1.0, y: 2.0)
let pointB = Point(x: 4.0, y: 6.0)
let distance = pointA.distanceTo (point: pointB)
```

Comment: thax alot Shripada :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you intended to make `distanceTo` a member of `Point`, so you have to put it inside the `struct` definition. Otherwise it won't know to what `self` refers:

```
struct Point {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double

    func distanceTo (point point: Point) -> Double {

        let a = abs(self.x - point.x)
        let b = abs(self.y - point.y)

        let c = sqrt(a * a + b * b)

        return c
    }
}

let pointA = Point(x: 1.0, y: 2.0)
let pointB = Point(x: 4.0, y: 6.0)
let distance = pointA.distanceTo (point: pointB)
```

By the way, rather than requiring `point:`, often you'd incorporate that in the method name:

```
struct Point {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double

    func distanceToPoint(point: Point) -> Double {

        let a = abs(self.x - point.x)
        let b = abs(self.y - point.y)

        let c = sqrt(a * a + b * b)

        return c
    }
}

let pointA = Point(x: 1.0, y: 2.0)
let pointB = Point(x: 4.0, y: 6.0)
let distance = pointA.distanceToPoint(pointB)
```

Comment: Yes Thanx You Rob, i'am new and try exploring the feature and how use it properly, thanx for helping me.